# How to navigate to a specific section of a page based on a dynamic value of a child element?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have these dynamic generted divs in HTML and populated with PHP data:

```
<?php foreach (get_all_locations() as $cards) : ?>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="centered">
      <div class="div_container">
        <p class="location_id_el"><?php echo $cards['id']; ?></p>
        <span onclick="edit_button_request(<?php json_encode($cards); ?>)"><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></span>
        <p><?php echo $cards['name']; ?></p> 
          <div id="main_address_div">
            <div id="address_div">
              <p><?php echo $cards['streetname'] . ' ' . $cards['streetnumber'] . ' '; ?></p>
            </div>                
          </div>                  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

now, I would like to navigate to a specific div using Javascript:

```
function myNavFunction(){
  let i = document.getElementById('location_id_el').value; //here I get the id of that element
  if(i === 4) document.location.href = ""; //here I want to navigate to the parent div of that element
}
```

any suggestions?!

Comment: You should use anchor tags.

Comment: if `i` is equals to `4`, and you say that `i` is the id, then you want to navigate to the element with id 4?

Comment: As suggested above. Use <a> tag. Also you are trying to get by id="location_id_el" but it's a class attribute in the code.